# JavaScript operador con objetos

Tags: javascript, operador

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y tengo una duda sobre un código y he encontrado una respuesta que aclarará mis dudas, el código es el siguiente:

```js
if (prop === "tracks" && !object[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks"))
```

La parte que no entiendo es qué hace el operador `!` con el objeto, o sea, qué significa exactamente. Hasta donde sé el operador se usa `!=`, evaluando si 2 valores son distintos.

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, ahora lo veo mucho más claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` es el operador de negación, cuando va con un igual -> `!=` lo que haces es comprobar si es `diferente`, que es la negación de `igual`.

En este caso, `object[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks")` devolverá `true` si el objeto que se encuentra ahí tiene la propiedad "tracks", al negarlo estás negando el booleano, es decir, si devuelve `true` lo conviertes a `false` y viceversa.

El código del `if` quedaría interpretado así: "Si `prop` es igual a "tracks" y  `object[id]` **NO** tiene la propiedad "tracks"

---

A continuación te dejo algunos ejemplos de uso de `!`:

```js
/*
  * Primero declaro un par de objetos que tendrán un nombre y una edad
  */
let pepe = {
  nombre: "pepe",
  edad: 16,
  estaEstudiando: true,
};

let juanito = {
  nombre: "juanito",
  edad: 21,
  estaEstudiando: false,
};
// Función que devolverá true si la edad es igual o superior a 18
const mayorDeEdad = (persona) => persona.edad >= 18;

console.log(
  "Negando el resultado de la función en la primera llamada, obtenemos true en ambos casos, aunque pepe claramente no tiene los 18 años aun!"
);
console.log("Pepe es mayor de edad?", !mayorDeEdad(pepe));
console.log("Juanito es mayor de edad?", mayorDeEdad(juanito));
console.log(
  "Ahora se niega el boolean juanito.estaEstudiando, y el resultado de esta operación será True"
);
console.log(
  "Juanito es un estudiante mayor de edad?",
  mayorDeEdad(juanito) && !juanito.estaEstudiando
);
```

---

Los ejemplos son un poco tontos, pero creo que demuestran el uso del `!` de manera sencilla ^^